# PowerShell Error when installing Node.js with NVS

Tags: node.js, powershell

I'm trying to install Node.js with NVS in PowerShell. The NVS command: `nvs add lts` works fine. But, when I use the command: `nvs use node/14.17.2/xx64`, I get the following output: https://pastebin.com/s7ntmVp1. I don't know what went wrong or how to fix this. If anyone can help, it'd be very appreciated

Comment: `The string is missing the terminator: ".`. the answer is in the error(;

Comment: What string though?

Comment: I get the same error when I use `nvs use "node/14.17.2/x64"`.

Comment: I can only make suggestions from what I see. Are you able to post the full error to include how you're calling the command?

Comment: The Pastebin link I put in the original question is the full error. However, in that error where it says `At C:\Users\wilso\AppData\Local\nvs\nvs_tmp_1786897507.ps1:1 char:1518'`, that location is this: https://pastebin.com/BiWeVLZw. I'm calling the command using `nvs use node/14.17.2/x64`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to `-replace` there? `"/.*` means _Match the character “/” literally, Match any single character that is not a line break character (Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy))_